# Using lambda's for ECS auto deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

I am about at my wits end with this one. I am currently working on setting up an auto deployment for a aws application. The application is running inside of ECS without a load balancer.

The idea here is that when a new docker image get pushed to ECR, cloudTrail picks up the log, cloudWatch triggers and alarm, said alarm goes to SNS, and SNS triggers a lambda to deploy. So far I have everything working except the lambda.

The code I am using is in python and is as follows:

```
import boto3
import pprint
import os

region = "us-east-2"
client = boto3.client('ecs', region_name=region)


response = client.list_task_definitions(familyPrefix= 'stage-dcs-task-000', status='ACTIVE')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.register_task_definition(
        family='stage-dcs-task-000',
        networkMode='bridge',
        containerDefinitions=[
            {
                'name': 'dcs-stage-container-000',
                'image': 'ecrUrlHere:latest',
                'cpu': 10,
                'memory': 500,
                'portMappings': [
                    {
                        'containerPort': 8080,
                        'hostPort': 80,
                        'protocol': 'tcp'
                    },
                ],
                'essential': True,
            },
        ],
    )
    taskDefinitionRev = response['taskDefinition']['family'] + ':' + str(response['taskDefinition']['revision'])


    response = client.update_service(
        cluster='stage-secretName-conversation-service',
        service='stage-dcs-service-000',
        desiredCount=1,
        taskDefinition=taskDefinitionRev,
        deploymentConfiguration={
            'maximumPercent': 200,
            'minimumHealthyPercent': 100
        },
        forceNewDeployment=True
    )
```

Now, this lambda fails with the error

```
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateService operation: The container stage-dcs-container-000is not valid. The value for 'containerName' must already be specified in the task definition. Registry: ARN-LINK-HERE"
```

Looking at what gets created in AWS, the task definition was created correctly, and the container was named and configured correctly. Based on what I understand from the docs, my call to update-service is correct, I just have no idea why the container name would be invalid.

Something interesting to note, is I though the container names might have to be unique. So I started add the task revision number to the end of the container name in place of the 000, however, I always get back stage-dcs-container-000 back as the invalid name and have no idea where it might be coming from. Any ideas here?

After doing some more debugging I have figured out that it is the container name within the current task definition that is throwing the error. Based on container name rules, I cannot have dashes, so I changed them to underscores, but the same issues still persists.

resources: this is the tutorial I  have been following https://medium.com/@YadavPrakshi/automate-zero-downtime-deployment-with-amazon-ecs-and-lambda-c4e49953273d

Answer (score 0):

It took a little while for me to figure this one out, but I eventually got it solved. Truth be told I am not 100% sure what the fix was, but I know there were at least two errors.

The first was the fact that I had somehow managed to fall into a state where I had illegal characters in the name of different parts of the stack. To give an explicit example, I have dashes (-) in the name of the containers, which is an illegal character. To solve this is just ended up recreating the whole tech stack using camel casing.

The second was I had some error in the lambda function, specifically in the creation of the task revision. What I ended up noticing what that when I created things via the cli I somehow missed the docker requirement. How I got around this was I created the task revision in the AWS consul and then just copied the json into to register_task_definition method inside the lambda. This is what I started with that DID NOT WORK.

```
response = client.register_task_definition(
        family='stage-dcs-task-000',
        networkMode='bridge',
        containerDefinitions=[
            {
                'name': 'dcs-stage-container-000',
                'image': 'ecrUrlHere:latest',
                'cpu': 10,
                'memory': 500,
                'portMappings': [
                    {
                        'containerPort': 8080,
                        'hostPort': 80,
                        'protocol': 'tcp'
                    },
                ],
                'essential': True,
            },
        ],
    )
```

this is what I finished with that DOES WORK.

```
response = client.register_task_definition(
        containerDefinitions=[
            {
                "portMappings": [
                    {
                        "hostPort": 80,
                        "protocol": "tcp",
                        "containerPort": 8080
                    }
                ],
                "cpu": 10,
                "environment": [],
                "mountPoints": [],
                "memoryReservation": 500,
                "volumesFrom": [],
                "image": "image uri here",
                "essential": True,
                "name": "productionDCSContainer"
            }
        ],
        family="productionDCSTask",
        requiresCompatibilities=[
            "EC2"
        ],
        networkMode="bridge"
    )
```

It should be noted that it is easy to fall into a state where you dead lock on the revision update, that is to say you have something like minPercentage = 100, maxPercentage = 100 and desired = 1. In this case, AWS will never kill the running instance to start the update. A way around this is have minInstance = 0, maxInstance = 200% and have forceNewDeployment = True.